# What is the policy for official apt packages moving to old-releases?

Tags: apt, official-repositories

When do the apt packages get published to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and removed from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ for a given Ubuntu release?

As at 2020-06-11, this is the current state for recently end of life releases:

```
Release       | End of life | archive.ubuntu.com | old-releases.ubuntu.com
============================================================================
10.04 lucid   | 2015-04-30  | No                 | Yes
12.04 precise | 2017-04-28  | Yes                | Yes
14.04 trusty  | 2019-04*    | Yes                | No
```

End of life dates are from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.

Is there an established policy on when the apt packages get moved?

<sup>*Trusty's end of Standard Support is 2019-04 but End Of Life is 2022-04 for paid Extended Security Maintenance.</sup>